# r - mapview cant handle big sf dataframe

Tags: r, gis, android-mapview, r-sf

Im trying to visualize a large **sf dataframe** with around 1000 rows containing **linestrings** with **mapview**::mapview() in **R**. Unfortunately a warning comes up when I perform the command:

```
mapview(data.frame)

Warning message:
In leaflet_sfc(sf::st_geometry(x), map = map, zcol = zcol, color = clrs,  :
  the supplied feature layer has more points/vertices than the set threshold.
  using special rendering function, hence things may not behave as expected from a standard leaflet map,
  e.g. you will likely need to zoom in to popup-query features

  to see the number of points/vertices of the layer use 'npts(x)'
  to see the threshold for the feature type use 'mapview:::getMaxFeatures(x)'
  to adjust the threshold use argument 'maxpoints'
```

And then I try to export as html and I get:

## R code execution error

And the saved file is 0 kb. I would be grateful if there is a fix or a workaround with some other function from the package maybe ?

I posted this question on the gis stack exchange as well but I think it might be of help to post here as well.

Comment: Disclaimer: mapview developer here. This behaviour (and the accompanying warning) is intended to be smart and switch to a mode that is usually a little better at displaying large features that might otherwise cause the map to become less responsive. Admittedly, having a universal threshold that works for all geometry types in all situations (e.g. one large polygon with many vertices vs. many simple polygons) is hard and may not work always. The thresholds we implemented are empirically chosen. This behaviour will change in the near future when leaflet updates to 1.3.1.

Comment: Regarding your issue with saving the map as html, try setting `selfcontained = FALSE` which usually works well for larger geometries.

Comment: Your answer is always appreciated Tim. Thank you

Comment: I am always thankful for suggestions on how to improve the calculation of shape / geometry complexity which is done [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/blob/develop/R/sf.R#L285)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that helped fix the error:

1. adding maxpoints argument:

   `mapview::mapview(data.frame, maxpoints = 1000000)`

Seems this increased the previously set threshold for plotting maximum number of features.

2. setting `selfcontained = FALSE` for exporting as `.html` as proposed by TimSalabim